# Firestore authentication using token from Google +

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, oauth-2.0

I'm creating an app that uses Google Firestore to store product information. The user is supposed to login with google and gain access to the products they have added.

The app uses Angular and Ionic for native experience, but this makes me unable to use Firebase authentication, because neither redirect or popup authentication works in native setup. Popup opens up another browser and redirect doesn't work because the domain in native app is localhost. I managed to circumvent this problem by using GooglePlus authentication that is provided by Ionic. This returns an authentication token, which works at least in https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/

The problem starts, when I'm trying to use the token in https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1

By providing the correct scopes while doing the authentication I'm able to access the API, but when trying to access the collection "/projects/{app-id}/databases/(default)/documents/{collection}" I'm presented with the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

I'm testing the API query with postman and I'm providing the token in headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

Any time I'm including the Authorization header the query returns the error above. Even when I specify that the database should be open for anyone with the following rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when I have this rule enabled I'm able to fetch the collection contents by leaving the Authorization header from the query. But if I include the Authorization header the query fails and gives the "Missing or insufficient permissions." error.

The users that are logging in using GooglePlus do not have an account in Firebase, as they are completely new users to the app, so that might have something to do with the "Missing or insufficient permissions." error. While trying to find a solution I believe I read something about there having to be an user if there were any restricting rules being used in Firestore?

I understand that there are differences between the Firebase Id token and Oauth2 token, but as far as I understand, the Oauth2 token should work in Firestore given that it has the correct scope enabled. Now, I think there should be at least two potential solutions to this problem. Either I somehow gain access to the Firestore collections using the Oauth2 token provided by GooglePlus service or I use the Oauth2 token to sign in to Firebase without having to go through either the popup or redirect authentication.

My question is:

Is there any way to use the token provided by GooglePlus in order to authenticate requests to the Firestore API? If a user is required in order to use the Firestre API, is it possible to create a new user if it doesn't exist using the GooglePlus token?

If this won't work, is it possible to use the GooglePlus token in Firebase authentication flow to bypass the need for either redirect or popup auth? Can I somehow pass the GooglePlus token to the Firebase authentication library and gain a new token through that? This would automatically create a new user and include the new token correctly to all of the queries without additional hassle.

I tried multiple different versions of rules in the Firestore admin center, but none of them worked when the Authorization header was included in the Query. As far as I understand at least the first version should work automatically in every case, since it always returns true and the next version should work if the request contains auth token:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

```
rules_version = ‘2’;
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Neither of these work with the Authorization header.

EDIT: I also tried to exchange the Oauth2 token for a Firebase ID token through

POST: [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=[CUSTOM_TOKEN]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=%5BCUSTOM_TOKEN%5D)

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth

But apparently Oauth2 token is not a valid custom token, and this just means the custom token is supposed to be created by for example a nodejs server that uses Firebase libraries to create a custom token.

This resulted into following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badRequest"
            }
        ],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "service": "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: I was able to circumvent this problem by using the firebase authentication provided by [capacitor-firebase](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase) by capawseome. I had some problems with this plugin though. At first it crashed the whole app, but after going through the requirements to install GooglePlus on Ionic it also made the capacitor-firebase plugin work.